# UNKNOWN classes in dumpheap sos plugin in linux

Tags: .net, linux, memory-leaks, lldb, sos

I try to detect memory leak on my .net core server and make memory dump via gcore. Try to analyze it via lldb and sos on debian 9.

```
ulimit -c unlimited
sudo gcore -o dump $(pidof dotnet)
sudo lldb-4.0 $(which dotnet) --core ./dump.MY_PID
(lldb) plugin load /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.1/libsosplugin.so
sos DumpHeap -stat
```

so, I have big table with mt, count, size and objname

But all my classes is UNKNOWN

```
...
00007f754af190b8      650        26000 UNKNOWN
00007f754b339df0      512        32768 UNKNOWN
00007f7549e8d718        6        35692 System.UInt16[]
00007f754c4e9e10      679        38024 UNKNOWN
00007f7549eb3138      482        61696 System.IO.FileStream
00007f754a155468      203        74208 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Entry[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib],[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib]][]
00007f754af198f8      695        90088 UNKNOWN
00007f7549e910d0      173        90696 System.Object[]
00007f7549e8a790     1010        98996 System.Int32[]
00007f7549e94ef0      361       417304 System.Char[]
00007f7549e950f0     1826       677178 System.Byte[]
00007f7549ea8a20    12844      1046724 System.String
00000000009628b0      809      2671130      Free
```

I think, that I should set symbols. But... I copy it to CLR folder `/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.1/` and try to use `add-dsym` command. Nothing change...
How can I have normal dump with full stack?

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/debug-linux-dumps):

> Other tools like gdb or gcore can also be used to create core dumps
> but may miss state needed for managed debugging, resulting in
> "UNKNOWN" type or function names during analysis.

[createdump](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/docs/design/coreclr/botr/xplat-minidump-generation.md) is the recommended tool for creating core dumps on Linux containing both native and managed information.

[Here](https://github.com/dotnet/diagnostics/blob/master/documentation/debugging-coredump.md#getting-symbols) is a documentation on downloading the host program, modules and symbols for the core dump.

Additionaly:

> Once LLDB starts, it may be necessary to use the setsymbolserver
> command to point at the correct symbol location (setsymbolserver -ms
> to use Microsoft's symbol server or setsymbolserver -directory 
> to specify a local path). Native symbols can be loaded by running
> loadsymbols. At this point, SOS commands can be used to analyze the
> dump.